# I'm Trying to create table "User" in DB with using spring data JPA. How can I do that?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, create-table

why can't I create table in db - "user" using spring data JPA ?

```
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE, force = true)
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "user")
public class User implements UserDetails {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    private final String username;
    private final String password;
    private final String fullName;
    private final String street;
    private final String city;
    private final String state;
    private final String zip;
    private final String phoneNumber;
}
```

I get an error while initializing the program

```
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "create table user (id bigint not null, city varchar(255)...
```

I change Class name from "user" to "users" and the problem was solved but what is the reason of that error ?

Answer (score 0):

`user` is a reserved word in SQL and Postgres. Many databases have reserved words, so you can run into collision sometimes.

Actually, JPA supports the following syntax for specifiyng the tablename (you can escape the table name)

```
@Table(name="\"user\"")
```

but it may cause problems in the future (in a query for example) and you should avoid using reserved words

So it is better to use `users` word instead